# Conda installed scalene python package not executing

Tags: python, profiler, scalene

I get the following error when I try to run scalene from the command line:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\bld\scalene_1668720941069\_h_env\python.exe"  "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\envs\gis\Scripts\scalene.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall scalene with conda:

`conda remove scalene`

And install it with pip:

`python3 -m pip install -U scalene`

It helped in my case.